# Find if a binary number when converted to a decimal number is a power of two or not?

Tags: java, regex

i need a regex to check if a given binary number when converted to decimal is a power of 2 or not.

Comment: This is beyond of regex, calculation needed, you'd better convert with code by yourself

Comment: I was attempting a hackerrank problem and this is the problem statement. I couldn't figure out how?

Comment: I don't think you can use regex for this kind of problem

Comment: If your input is a string of 1's and 0's representing an unsigned binary integer, it should be pretty simple. Are you sure you need to convert to decimal?

Comment: @YerramsettyGDSuryaPrakash asking for the solution of a challenge here, isn't this a bit weird? Especially, it's pretty simple, just think about how each number beeing power of 2 is represented as binary? Should be clear that it's always a single 1 the rest zero

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a binary number is a power of 2, then its leftmost bit must be a `1` and all other bits after that (if any) must be `0`.

Therefore, this regex will do the job:

```
^10*$
```

If the number can have leading zeros, use `0*` at the start to match them as well:

```
^0*10*$
```

Comment: @SPlatten "first digit" was a bit confusing, I guess. Changed it to "leftmost".